# Bluetooth paired but no COM port

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, arduino

So I've built an Arduino module with a Bluetooth chip (HM-10) and it pairs succesfully with my Windows laptop. They both use Bluetooth BLE.

The problem is that the pairing doesn't seem to open a COM port, so I have no way to actually communicate across the connection.

There are no COM port connections when I go into Bluetooth settings->COM Ports, even though Windows is definitely telling me that the pairing was successfull.

Does anyone know why this could be?

Thanks for reading

Lukas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem on a Mac. Turns out it's not a problem. BLE doesn't quite work like regular ol' Bluetooth and you won't have a COM port. You need to write your own middleware to take care of the communication between the Arduino and your computer.

There are different projects working on that in Python or Node.js. A simple google search should provide with a proficiency of solutions.

Comment: In BLE there are not services; now they are called "profiles" and you have to implement your own to communicate (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy#Applications))..